# RegExp.exec infinite loop

Tags: javascript, regex

Why I have infinite loop in this

```
var sRegexp=new RegExp("([\\d\\s\\.]+)\\s*("+iconsStr+")","g"),value;
var nodeValue=this.nodeValue;

while(value=sRegexp.exec(nodeValue)) {
     alert(sRegexp.lastIndex);
}
```

lastIndex is infilite too and value return equal results (as without 'g' flag), can't understand why.

UPDATE: I solved it, the problem was that I used noveValue.reaplce() in while(), sorry for I don't posted all code...

Comment: Well your while condition never changes, so how can it become false and leave the loop?

Comment: Since you always use the same data on the RegExp and that results in a match, there is always a truthy value continuing the loop forever.

Comment: RegExp.exec must return null when it in end of string? And why lastIndex increase infinitly?

Comment: can you share what value you are passing?

Comment: In nodeValue something like "10 $ test text text 5 $ text text". RegExp.exec returns only 10 $ (first match) and increase lastIndex infinitly

Comment: And what is `iconsStr`?

Comment: `iconsStr` is $|other_currencies

Comment: Can you share only the relevant code without variables whose values are not defined within your question itself? Please make a working snippet using `<>`.

Comment: hm this works find in test https://jsfiddle.net/6vwfwzz7/

Answer (score 0):

Because the condition for while loop matches every time since you have to truncate or change any of the variables.

```
Like:


var sRegexp=new RegExp("([\\d\\s\\.]+)\\s*("+iconsStr+")","g");
var value=sRegexp.exec(nodeValue);
console.log(value);
    for(item in value)
    {
       if(!isNaN(parseInt(item)))
       {
         console.log(item + ", " + value[item]); //in this item return the index of every array element and value[item] provide the matched value.
       }


    }
```

Comment: I try assign value=""; but this not helped... And .exec must return NULL when it in end of string, but this not happend...